# How magento understand directive code

Tags: magento, directive

Can any body help me to understand how magento understand directive in cms page or any where it is used.Eg.suppose we use {{store url}} then how it identify. can we create our custom directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMS tags/directives are handled inside

```
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter
```

You can override/extend this to add your own quite easily. there's a [few pages](http://www.spinonesolutions.com/2010/04/magento-cms-tags-directives/) with info on the default directives: